# How can I repair scratches in a wooden window sill?

Tags: trim, damage

My blind bound up last night and in removing it from its supports I scraped the window sill and damaged the finish. What would be the best way to touch this up?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: See also: All the questions on this site about fixing scratches in hardwood floors and cabinetry.

Comment: Look at the list of related questions to the right. If none of them help you, please [edit] your question to tell us what's specific and different about your situation.